# I want to map crawled properties to manged properties using csom (c#) in Sharepoint 2013. How can i do the same?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I want to map crawled properties to managed properties using csom (c#) in Sharepoint 2013. How can i do the same?